# Distributed Yarn Application

Tags: java, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, bigdata

when i have a job that is submitted on Ressources Manager via YArnClient 
The RM will instanciate an AM on one of the Node manager ,i suppose that my job was a jarFile , so this jarfile will be distributed on all the NM on the cluster then all the NM will excute the same jarFile , the same source code , can any one explain to me the scenario of excuting the same code source on NM ?